# Using Search Console API v3 (Search Analytics) without Oauth, just API key

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, authorization

I've tried this code and it works.

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/quickstart/quickstart-java

But it uses Oauth and it requires a redirect. Is there any way to use just an API key without having to redirect to a browser?

I understand I can just make http request using this:

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/

But I wonder if there's any Java API I can use, like in the first example.

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing. Did you find an answer?

Comment: It's 2 years later. Did you find an answer to that?

Comment: No, sorry, I stopped working on that long ago...